# Xilinx SDK is not updated by μblaze parameters

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-edk

I have modified the "system.mhs" file as follows :

```
begin microblaze 
// some lines of code 
 PARAMETER C_PVR = 2
 PARAMETER C_PVR_USER1 = 0x02
 PARAMETER C_PVR_USER2 = 0x0bb35
//some lines of code
End
```

when i build the hardware in Xps and export to xilinx SDK i do not see these parameters updated in xparameters.h. any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

A clean and rebuild of the standalone BSP project refreshes the xparameters.h file and updates it by the required parameters
Problem solved !!!